# trying to deploy service on the kubernetes but i keep getting the error this error"The Service "service-name" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value"

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

the screenshots are the code from vs code YML file and CMD error iam getting while am trying to apply the yml file[image]

Comment: when i try to apply the yml file on the cmd i get this...."deployment.apps/order unchanged
The Service "order" is invalid: spec.ports: Required value"

Comment: Welcome! Please [do not post code, errors and logs as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), but copy the relevant parts into the question instead, refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation of service wrong after `---` here full YAML block for reference

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: order
spec:
  selector:
    app: order
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8081
  type: ClusterIP
```

Reference document : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/service#services_of_type_clusterip

Answer (score 0):

You are missing indentation for the spec block(means add two space before all the lines after spec: )

It should be like

```yaml
spec:
  type: ClusterIp
  selector:
    app: order
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8081
```

Comment: its still giving me an error on the type..... unknown field "type" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.ServicePort;

Comment: Could you paste your yaml file?

Comment: Thanks alot Sherief it worked....i appreciate your assistance